# What is the best way to unit test a COM-Port abstracton library?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, winapi

I currently unit test our COM-Port library and some basic IO classes which build on it using a null modem cable and a second COM-Port. This works but its quite annoying because the cable needs to be pugged in for the test pass. I tried to use a file rather than the port but this fails because setting the baud rate is not supported by a file. Any tips or ideas? I have not  been unit testing for very long so I think I'm missing something.

Comment: A quick Google dance gave me this - [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Time machine back to the 90s?

Answer (score 1):

You should generally avoid external dependencies in unit tests -- they should be self contained, so one option is to [mock-out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) (or stub) the actual IO within the COM-port library if it is appropriately structured to do so, or create a mock for the entire library, so that calling code does not have to depend on the actual hardware.